# LaTeX doesn't recognize "et al." in the Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm using `Jabref` to manage my Bibliography.

Sometimes, I put directly:

> First Author et al.

when adding the article author's name in `Jabref`.

When compiling my `.tex` file, LaTeX doesn't recognize the `et. al` as more names. It takes it as a name/surname.

This is an example of a Bibliography entry in `Jabref`.

```
@ARTICLE{Wolf2003,  
  author = {Wolf, K.et al.},  
  title = {Compensation mechanism in tumor cell migration: mesenchymal–amoeboid
    transition after blocking of pericellular proteolysis},  
  journal = {J. Cell Biol.},  
  year = {2003},  
  volume = {160},  
  pages = {267–277},  
 }
```

This is a `.tex`MWE with the bib entry mentioned:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}  
\usepackage{cite}  
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{document}  
Here is the bib entry mentioned\cite{Wolf2003}  

\bibliography{bibfile} 
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image: Output of the <code>.tex</code> MWE mentioned above]
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should use the special keywords `and others`, so `author={Wolf, K. and others},`

Comment: I used "{random authors}" in author field, that way you can use anything you like... I guess it's the same as egreg said :)

Comment: I didn't understand what you mentioned about {random authors} @dingo_d

What did you mean? Thank you.

Comment: Just put what ever you want inside {} brackets ;)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The input conventions of BibTeX are rather strict; multiple authors must be separated by the `and` keyword:

```
author={Alpher, Ralph and Bethe, Hans and Gamow, George}
```

or, if you want to keep only initials,

```
author={Alpher, R. and Bethe, H. and Gamow, G.}
```

If you want only the first author and automatically add *et al.* in the bibliography, use the `others` keyword:

```
author={Alpher, R. and others}
```

Comment: *et* doesn't want the "dot". It is Latin and means *and*. *al.* stays for *alii*, *aliae*, *alia* and *alios*, hence you shorten it and put the "dot".

Comment: @Atcold Thanks, it was just a typo, I don't know how it slipped in and I'll remove it. I can ensure you that I *know* Latin. `;-)`

Answer (score 10):

I imagine two reasons for you to ask this question:

1. You only have partial information about your references → use [egreg's great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123607/64454) in this case.
2. What you really want is **how to display one author name only in your bibliography/citation**. (You here thus face a [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

The solution below answer this second question.

---

I would suggest you to **keep as much information as possible in your database** (in the event that you change your mind later or in another document).

To show only one author name in your bibliography, you can **use features of you bibliographical package**. With the package `biblatex`, the relevant option is `maxnames=<maximal number of authors to display>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[
        maxnames=1,%<---------- the key option
        style=authoryear-comp,
    ]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
        @book{keyone,
            author = {Single Author, A.},
            year = {2001},
            title = {Title},
            publisher = {Publisher},
        }
        @book{keytwo,
            author = {Firstof Threeauthors, J. and Secondof Threeauthors, E. and Thirdof Threeautors, G.},
            year = {2017},
            title = {A catchy title},
            publisher = {Same publisher},
        }
    \end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    First reference: \cite{keyone}. Second one: \cite{keytwo}.

    Which are these references' authors? \citeauthor{keyone} and \citeauthor{keytwo}, respectively.

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

Note that you can differentiate between the number of authors listed in a citation (option `maxcitenames=`), and in the bibliography (`maxbibnames=`). The option `maxnames=` just sets both of these options together.

If you have `max[x]names` > 1, you might want to specify the fallback number of cited names if your reference contains more than `max[x]names` authors. In other words, define:

> *If my reference has* x *authors or less, then cite all of them. Otherwise, cite only the* y *first authors, and append* 'et al'.

For that, you can use the `minnames=` option:

```
    \usepackage[
        maxnames=<x>,
        minnames=<y>,
    ]{biblatex}
```

Obviously, one assume `x >= y`. And similarly, you can define `mincitenames` and `minbibnames` separately.

Example with `maxnames=2, minnames=2`
[image]

Same example with `maxnames=2, minnames=1`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We know that et al. is Latin, and should thus appear in italic.

Thing is `author={Alpher, R. and others}` generates et al. as a normal font and not italic.

A quick, also dirty fix, modified from the above is the following:

```
author = {Smith {\textit{et al.}}, Fred}
```

Comment: The bibliography style should choose the typesetting style of the phrase resulting from `and others`.  This should not be set in the `.bib` file.

Answer (score -3):

Using suggestions above, I found that this works.

To write 
Fred Smith et al. 
I used 
author = {Smith {et al.}, Fred}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) And thank you for providing an answer to this question. At the same time, if your suggestion might "work" (in the sense that you see what you're expecting), your answer is "wrong". Indeed, "Smith et al." is *not* the name of the author; so it's not correct to store such information in the database. What you propose is thus a quick (and dirty) fix that might work, rather than a sustainable solution. (Nothing personal here: just a note for future readers.)