# How to add et all to references?

Tags: cross-referencing, thesis

I am writing a thesis and I would like to add "et all." to references. This problem is described here:

[LaTeX doesn't recognize "et al." in the Bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123600/latex-doesnt-recognize-et-al-in-the-bibliography)

The problem is that when I define it in file "references.bib", e.g.:

```
@article{reconstruction,
author = {A. Smith and others},
journal = {},
number = {},
pages = {},
title = {},
url = {},
volume = {},
year = {}
}
```

The result is "Smith, A. et al.", but I would like to get: "A. Smith et al.". How can I solve it? Thanks.

This is the template, which I am using:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwyOySLlDTB_a3R5aFZQNzVFRG8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The format for printing author names depends on the BibTeX style (`.bst` file) in use. Can you edit in a _minimal_ document showing the style you use?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you use the `biblatex` package that allows you to use _et al._ in some bibliographic styles, instead of using `bibtex` as seems to be your case. But is better if you can add a MWE.

Comment: The ordering of the first name (or its initial) and surname of the author -- i.e., "A. Smith" vs. "Smith, A." -- is determined by the bibliography style. Try the styles `abbrv` and `abbrvnat` and decide if one of them suits your needs.

Comment: It's `et al.` and its use is common. This comes of the French language and generally isn't translated.

Comment: @skpblack it comes from the latin `et alii`, actually.

Comment: Yes, excuse me, but French is a language  of Latin origin

Comment: @skpblack French comes from Latin, but that doesn't mean that all Latin expressions can be called "French". And this discussion has nothing to do with the OP's question ...

Comment: There are cases (i.e. bibliography or `bst` styles) where you want to list all of the authors. This is why the bibtex files should contain all of the authors. As Mico says/hints at, most `bst` files do in fact add *et al* automatically if there are many authors.

Comment: The bst is unknown, the title  does not match the question, the linked code (i think it may have been code) is not available. Nobody can answer this question.