# How can I manually include 'et al' in a biblatex reference?

Tags: biblatex

When I try to use "authorname et al" in the author field of my bibliography.bib, this is interpreted as part of the first author's name, and hence is not presented correctly. How can I use et al in my references list?

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of [LaTeX doesn't recognize “et al.” in the Bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123600/35864) (or [BibTeX: How can I automatically reduce long author lists to “xxx et al.”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95956/35864))

Comment: I couldn't find that one when I was searching, which is why I made this. Feel free to close if necessary. I ended up getting my answer from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197148/how-to-add-et-all-to-references), which was rather different, so I formatted to try to make it easier for users with this problem. Maybe I couldn't find that article cause it's tagged bibtex, rather than biblatex?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `authorname et al`, use `authorname and others`. This will be automatically converted to *et al.* in your document by `biblatex`.

Comment: It's not working for authorname and others@Dimpl

Comment: @SibaMishra It should really work. If it doesn't do it for you, please consider asking a new question about that with a full MWE.